# Manjaro Linux mouse doesn't work

Tags: mouse, manjaro

I've just now installed the Manjaro Linux on my laptop. My touchpad works perfectly but when I connect one mouse to the laptop that doesn't work.
Does anybody know how to make it work?

Comment: What's the version & flavour of manjaro you are running ? Did you connect the mouse via usb ? Did you try running `lsusb` or `dmesg | tail` to see if the mouse was detected ?

Comment: Does that mean the Touchpad doesn't work after connecting the mouse or the mouse or both?

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem, too. I see both of my external mouse and keyboards in `lsusb`, their LEDs are lit up, but their inputs are not being recognized by Manjaro.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem. When I looked in `lsusb`, I could see external mouse and keyboard were recognized. Their LEDs were lit up, too. However, their inputs are not being recognized by Manjaro.

I fixed the problem by installing `xf86-input-synaptics` and restarting.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a number of solution such as updating my kernel, following @crypdick's answer, restarting gnome, I found that the issue was relatively simple: I had a bluetooth mouse connected that for some reason was preventing me from clicking (but not from moving my cursor) on my trackpad.